# Does anyone have a Control Visualizer for VS 2005

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, debuggervisualizer

I am looking for the source and download of the Control Visualizer which is developed by Brett Johnson, but i am unable to find any links related for downloading the Visualizer and also unable to find any source code for the same.

I am using VS 2005, are there any links for or any other material related to this control visualizer which will help us a lot

Looking for favorable replies.

Answer (score 1):

I believe [this](http://blog.bretts.net/?p=9) is the visualizer you are refering to, however all the links on the page appear to be broken.

I have done a further bit of digging and managed to find a working link via the wayback machine on the internet archive.  You can download the code from this page:

http://web.archive.org/web/20060426073908/http://blog.bretts.net/?p=9

Comment: Thank you very much friend, for this, i also have spent months digging at the internet to find the source code or the control visualizer itself, but i am unable to get my hands on it.
Thank You very much for your time and the link to the control.
Now i will try to understand the logic and the working of the control.
Thanks